# Genymotion: Why is Android version 9.0 the highest I can use on an S10 emulator?

Tags: android-versions, samsung-galaxy-s-10, genymotion

I'm trying to replicate an issue a customer is having on their Samsung Galaxy S10 running Android version 11. When I spin up an S10 emulator, the highest Android version I can use is 9. Does anyone know why this would be, and if there's a way to get higher versions?

Comment: Genymotion is a closed source commercial software. How should we know why an emulator image is available or not?

Comment: @Robert 1) If Genymotion came with only a default set of emulator images that were most common, and you could download others, and someone knew how, that would be an example of knowing why an emulator image is available or not. 2) My second question was how to do that, if possible.

Comment: [Genymotion Cloud SaaS](https://support.genymotion.com/hc/en-us/articles/360007473658-Supported-Android-devices-templates-for-Genymotion-Cloud-SaaS) seems to have Galaxy S10 on Android 10 as a preview. However, we don't really know how Genymotion works with their images [since Samsung doesn't provide their system images in the first place](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52577939/2821954).

Comment: Your Genymotion seems to be outdated. When I select Samsung Galaxy S10 I can select Android 10 as the maximum. BTW: Such an the "Samsung Galaxy S10 Emulator" is just an AOSP emulator. Just the screen size and density seems to be identical to an original S10 (there not a single Samsung specific package installed).