# In Android Studio, which system image should I choose for a Pixel 4 emulator?

Tags: android-emulator, emulators, android-studio, google-pixel-4

In Android Studio, I'm adding a Pixel 4 virtual device. It asks me to select a `System Image`, and has the following one selected by default:

```
Release name: Pie
API Level: 28
ABI: x86
Target: Android 9.0 (Google Play)
```

There are others with API levels 29 and 30 that are shown but that I haven't downloaded yet. How do I decide which System Image to use for a Pixel 4?

Comment: Pixel 4 is still maintained by Google hence it has received update to Android 11. If you want to simulate that select the API30 image.

Comment: Hi Robert, would the general rule be "use the highest API level that existed when the device stopped being maintained by Google"?

Comment: Since [your previous question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/234525/44325) was also related to an emulator, may I know what you're trying to do and/or the specific concern you are having regarding the system image, so that we can focus and clarify those?

Comment: No, the general rule if you develop for a specific device is **"get a real physical device"**. An emulator is just for testing general compatibility to a certain Android version. It will never behave exactly like a real device. Therefore most app developers don't use the emulator at all, instead then have multiple physical test devices.